# Ansible docker-compose for each host in group

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ansible

I'm using Ansible with [Docker Compose](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_compose_module.html). As my `docker-compose.yml` (together with other dependencies which shall not be copied to the remote host) is located on the local machine, I'm running the playbook on `localhost`. But the services defined in the `docker-compose` file shall be executed on a remote host, defined in the `hosts` file using the `docker_host` variable.

Example:

```
# hosts
[webserver]
192.168.88.100
192.168.88.101
192.168.88.102
```

```
# playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - docker_compose:
      docker_host: tcp://192.168.88.100:2375
```

In the playbook is now one explicit ip address defined. My goal is to execute this task for each host defined in the group `webserver` without the need to manually create the task for each ip address.

Is this possible with ansible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like this :

```
# playbook.yml
- hosts: webserver
  tasks:
  - docker_compose:
      docker_host: "tcp://{{ ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }}:2375"
    delegate_to: localhost
```

`{{ ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }}` allows you to obtain the ip address of the host.

`delegate_to: localhost` allows you to specify localhost as the host to execute tasks on.

Comment: perfect, this solved the issue. Thanks! The `delegate_to` command was the one missing for me. For the ip address I'm using `inventory_hostname` right now, which gives me the name as defined in the inventory.